# How to add custom info window flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I want to add this custom widget to my marker. I have designed the widget but I don't know how to position it on the marker.

How do I customise it like that to always appear on the info window position. Its wrapped in a positioned widget but I can't get to place it on the info window position.

[image: marker image]

```
Stack(
        children: [
          AnimatedPositioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:
              30,left: 15,
                  right: 15,bottom: 10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(0),
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5))),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    '500 USD',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      color: customBlue,
                      fontSize: _sizeConfig.textSize(
                        context,
                        Converters.configSize(14),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  RatingBar.builder(
                    initialRating: 3.5,
                    unratedColor: Colors.grey
                        .withOpacity(0.5),
                    minRating: 1,
                    allowHalfRating: true,
                    itemSize: 20,
                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: 5,
                    itemPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
                    itemBuilder: (context, _) => Icon(
                      Icons.star,
                      color: customRed,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              width: 163,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: What kind of map do you use ? Please mention it

Comment: GoogleMaps bro,

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no easy way to implement it, but there's a full tutorial including both a creating an [image from a widget](https://medium.com/flutter-community/export-your-widget-to-image-with-flutter-dc7ecfa6bafb) and using it as a marker's icon. Check it out: https://medium.com/swlh/using-material-icons-as-custom-google-map-markers-in-flutter-3e854de22e2

Comment: Did you find a solution need the same feature for my app.
@customapps

Answer (score 3):

Please use cutsom packages

[custom_info_window: ^1.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_info_window)

[clippy_flutter 2.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/clippy_flutter/versions/2.0.0-nullsafety.1/example)

```
Stack(
      children: [
          markers: _markers,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          zoomControlsEnabled: false,
          gestureRecognizers: {
            Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                () => ScaleGestureRecognizer()),
          }, 
        ),
        CustomInfoWindow(
          controller: _customInfoWindowController,
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
          offset: 50,
        ),
      ],
    ),

    _markers.add(
  Marker(
    markerId: const MarkerId("marker_id"),
    position: _latLng,
    onTap: () {
      _customInfoWindowController.addInfoWindow!(
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Bevel(
              cutLength: 10,
              child: Container(
                width: 120.0,
                height: 140.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
    ],),
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try [custom_info_window](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_info_window). It is a package that allows widget based custom info window for google_maps_flutter. By using this, you will be able to move your widget like info window on the top of the map's marker.

Comment: Facing this issue,
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(103)] Dart Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'call' was called on null.

Answer (score 0):

There are no easy apis to use your widget as markers in the google maps plugin.

But there are some tricks. You should export the widget to the image and pass it through `BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes`.

Useful links how to do it:

[Widget to Image](https://medium.com/flutter-community/export-your-widget-to-image-with-flutter-dc7ecfa6bafb)

[Pass widget converted to Image to Google map](https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/creating-custom-markers-on-google-maps-in-flutter-apps)

If it seems like boilerplate code, you can use the flutter_map plugin by leaflet

[flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map)